# How to display an image when hovering over its title in a View?

Tags: views

In my style sheet (which does seem to be loaded), I have

```
.snhover_img a { position:relative; }
.snhover_img a span { position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99; }
.snhover_img a:hover span {
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
}
```

And in the Title field of my View, I have Rewrite results as

```
<div class="snhover_img">
      <a href="#">{{ title }}<span><img src="/stelnews{{ field_issue_png }}"  /></span></a>
</div>
```

But I always see both the title and the image. Nothing happens on hover. 
The debugger shows[image: What debugger shows]. What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: I am thinking that the style sheet is not really loading. If not, how do I fix that?

Comment: I am thinking that the style sheet is not really loading. If not, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I post as answer because I have not reach 50 reputation to post as comment.
When you debug `.snhover_img a span` is the style `{ position:absolute; display:none; z-index:99; }` applied?